# main.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null

Tags: javascript, angular, chartist.js

I am using Chartist with angular to create charts. The problem is that my charts don't display when I run the server and I get this error on the console. When I refresh the page, charts show up. How can I solve this?
I printed data on the console to check if they are coming right and they are.

### line.component.ts file

```
        import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
    import { ChartData } from '../chart.data.namespace';
    import * as Chartist from 'chartist';
    import { NChartist } from '../NChartist.namespace';
    import {
      IBarChartOptions,
      IChartistAnimationOptions,
      IChartistData
    } from 'chartist';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-line',
      templateUrl: './line.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./line.component.css'],
      encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None,
    })
    export class LineComponent implements OnInit {
      chartline: any;
      @Input() data: ChartData.LabelValue[];
      constructor() {
      }
    
      ngOnInit() {
    
        this.createLineChart();
      }
      createLineChart() {
        let linedata: NChartist.Data = new NChartist.Data();
    
        this.prepareLineData(linedata);
        const prepared_l_data = {
          series: [linedata.series],
          labels: linedata.labels,
        }
        this.chartline = new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart-line', prepared_l_data,{})
        console.log(this.chartline);
        this.chartline.update();
        this.startAnimationForLineChart(this.chartline);
    
    
    
    
      }
      prepareLineData(linedata) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
          linedata.series[i] = this.data[i].value;
          linedata.labels[i] = this.data[i].label;
        }
      }
    
      startAnimationForLineChart(chart){
        let seq: any, delays: any, durations: any;
        seq = 0;
        delays = 80;
        durations = 500;
    
        chart.on('draw', function(data) {
          if(data.type === 'line' || data.type === 'area') {
            data.element.animate({
              d: {
                begin: 600,
                dur: 700,
                from: data.path.clone().scale(1, 0).translate(0, data.chartRect.height()).stringify(),
                to: data.path.clone().stringify(),
                easing: Chartist.Svg.Easing.easeOutQuint
              }
            });
          } else if(data.type === 'point') {
                seq++;
                data.element.animate({
                  opacity: {
                    begin: seq * delays,
                    dur: durations,
                    from: 0,
                    to: 1,
                    easing: 'ease'
                  }
                });
            }
        });
    
        seq = 0;
    };
    
    
    
    }
```

### line.component.html

```
 <body>
    <div class="card card-chart">
        <div class="card-header card-header-warning">
            <div class="ct-chart-line" id="chartline"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Line Chart</h4>
            <p class="card-category">
                <span class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></i> 55% </span> increase in today
                sales.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="stats">
                <i class="material-icons">access_time</i> updated 4 minutes ago
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to ensure all html is complete when you call createLineChart().
ngOnInit() isn't the best cycle hook to call a queryselector. Try to call it in ngAfterViewInit() method without forgetting to implement AfterViewInit :

```
export class LineComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit
```

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
this.createLineChart();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I already tried importing AfterViewInit but unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Just to be sure about a timing problem, try rxjs timer : timer(250).subscribe(r=>{this.createLineChart();});